# Do OpenLayers maps always show/flash an empty screen while zooming?

Tags: openlayers

When double-clicking on an [OpenLayers map](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/bing-tiles.html), the screen is momentarily blank while the next zoom level draws.

Is this avoidable? It's not ideal, given that many other mapping APIs show a smooth zooming effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to change the layer transitionEffect to 'resize'. According to OpenLayers documentation:

**transitionEffect**

{String} The transition effect to use when the map is panned or zoomed.

There are currently two supported values

- null

  No transition effect (the default).
- resize

  Existing tiles are resized on zoom to provide a visual effect of the zoom having taken place immediately.  As the new tiles become available, they are drawn over top of the resized tiles.

> http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.transitionEffect

Comment: Thanks. It's not quite as smooth as some of the other APIs but this is a definite improvement.